# Regular Expression Validation not allowing string type ab ,cd

Tags: asp.net

I am using Regular Expression Validator in my application.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Notes" ControlToValidate="txtNotes" ErrorMessage="Invalid Notes Input!" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>.
```

When I enter text "ab ,cd" in my textbox it shows error message "Invalid Notes Input!" .
While it takes string "ab, cd" and ""ab,cd".

Thanks

Comment: What are the valid inputs in your textbox? Can you add some samples? Is blank valid?

Comment: @unlimit "The RegularExpressionValidator does not perform validation on an empty string." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.validationexpression.aspx

Comment: Yeah, totally forgot it. That is why we have the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I enter text "ab ,cd"** assuming you want to accept space and comma

Your expression should be

```
 ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z, ]+$"
```

Comment: it is still not working, same result. It is accepting spaces, it is acceping a, b i.e. a, (space)b but not a (space),b

Comment: @rahulaggarwal, I have tested it, its working fine on my end.

Comment: did you tried with a(space),b. Because it is not working at my end

Comment: @rahulaggarwal, yes I did, I suggest you to create a new web application or web site and just check it. might be error is at somewhere else.

Comment: yes, it worked may be it was considering space as some special character because I was using copy paste. Thanks